# Open vbp file with text editor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a vbp file that I would like to open with a computer without vb.  I don't need to run the file, but I would just like to look at the source code.  Is it possible to do this with a text editor?

Answer (score 2):

`.vbp` files are Visual Basic project files; they don't contain any VB source code.

That being said, you can certainly open source code files in something like Notepad or Wordpad, or some other text editor equivalent. The source code is just plain text.

In Notepad and Wordpad, just open them up and use `File -> Open` or `Ctrl+O`. (Set the file type filter to `All Types (*.*)` or `All Documents (*.*)`.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it's a plain-text file.

Note that the VBP file is the *project* file; it references the other files, but does not contain source code.
However, the actual source files (.frm, .bas, etc) are also plain-text.